# Make a sprite keep bouncing

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, collision

I'd like to know if there's any way to make a sprite have the same "amount of bouncing" when colliding with other objects in Sprite Kit. I mean, I want it move with the same force after a collision. I have set both colliding objects restitution to 1.0 but after some collisions and in a certain angle, the sprite decelerates.

Comment: Turn off friction: `self.physicsBody?.friction = 0`

Comment: @Knight0fDragon nope, its velocity is still decreasing after every collision

Comment: Did you set it to both the physics world and your node?

Comment: Try setting `node.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0`

Comment: @0x141E Yep, that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:
Change the gravity of the physics world to zero

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
```

Second:
Reduce the body’s linear velocity (LinearDamping)

```
myBall.physicsBody!.linearDamping = 0
```

Third: 
Change the bounciness of the physics body

```
myBall.physicsBody!.restitution = 0
```

Fourth:
Change the Friction

```
myBall.physicsBody!.friction = 0
```

See the whole explanation in the DevelopApps.org website
http://www.developapps.org/sprite-kit-tutorial-how-to-make-a-node-keep-bouncing/